# Comparing times only within an interval in js

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, luxon

I am trying to compare only time (regardless of the date) in js. First I need a way to compare times so I came across the luxon library which works well.

But, there is a problem when comparing intervals across midnight. For example: `20:00 < 01:00 < 10:00` should evaluate to true, the luxon's library returns a false. Which makes sense because `20:00 < 01:00` can evaluate differently when in different intervals. These is what I would be expecting:

`20:00 < 01:00 < 10:00 == true // but it evaluates as false using luxon's interval`

`00:00 < 01:00 < 10:00 == true`

This is the code I have so far:

```
const from = DateTime.fromISO('20:00');
const to = DateTime.fromISO('10:00');
const value = DateTime.fromISO('01:00');

const interval = Interval.fromDateTimes(from, to);

console.log(interval.contains(valueTime)); // returns false instead of true
```

Answer (score 0):

Substract on day from `from`, if `from` is bigger than `to`.
And substract on day from `value`, if it is bigger than `to`, to get it into the interval.

```js
let from = luxon.DateTime.fromISO('20:00');
const to = luxon.DateTime.fromISO('10:00');
let value = luxon.DateTime.fromISO('01:00');

if(from > to)
{
  from = from.minus({ days: 1 });
}

if(value > to)
{
  value = value.minus({ days: 1 });
}

const interval = luxon.Interval.fromDateTimes(from, to);

console.log(interval.contains(value));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/3.4.3/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-gUQcFuEaDuAEqvxIQ9GDdMcCeFmG5MPnoc6ruJn+nyCNHrHM2oB97GOVLIOiixzTxPYmIfEQbOoQmx55UscLyw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Testing different values:

```
19:00 -> false
21:00 -> true
01:00 -> true
09:00 -> true
11:00 -> false
```

Seems to be the desired behavior.

Comment: that will not work if one is greater than the other. So from 10:00 to 23:00 next day

Answer (score 0):

You need the date unless the to is always smaller than the from across midnight

```js
const from = luxon.DateTime.fromISO('2023-11-03T20:00');
const to = luxon.DateTime.fromISO('2023-11-04T10:00');
const valueTime = luxon.DateTime.fromISO('2023-11-04T01:00');

const interval = luxon.Interval.fromDateTimes(from, to);
console.log(from.toString(),"\n",to.toString(),"\n",valueTime.toString())
console.log(interval.contains(valueTime)); // returns false instead of true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/3.4.3/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-gUQcFuEaDuAEqvxIQ9GDdMcCeFmG5MPnoc6ruJn+nyCNHrHM2oB97GOVLIOiixzTxPYmIfEQbOoQmx55UscLyw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```